# siddhi - Can't retrieve event message from rabbitmq with siddhi

Tags: java, rabbitmq, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String siddhiApp = "@App:name('TestExecutionPlan') " 
            + "define stream FooStream (teste string);  "
            + "@info(name = 'query1')  " 
            + "@source(type ='rabbitmq', "
            + "uri = 'amqp://test:test@192.168.99.100:5672', " 
            + "exchange.name = 'amq.topic', "
            + "exchange.type = 'topic', "
            + "routing.key= '#', "
            + "queue.name = 'siddhi-queue', "
            + "@map(type='text')) " 
            + "Define stream BarStream (test string); "
            + "from FooStream select test insert into BarStream; ";

    SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();

    SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(siddhiApp);

    siddhiAppRuntime.start();

    siddhiAppRuntime.addCallback("FooStream", new StreamCallback() {
        public void receive(Event[] event) {
            EventPrinter.print(event);
        }
    });
```

}

This code, can't retrive event message from rabbitmq.

I can see the connection and channel into rabbitmq dashboard, all the messages posted into exchange are delivered to other binding queues.

Comment: kindly help me out about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673540/using-siddhi-io-rabbitmq-with-a-java-library-syntax-error-in-siddhiql-no-viabl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the callBack to "BarStream" which is the source. You can try out the following sample.

```
    @Test
public void rabbitmqSourceTest() throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicInteger eventCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    String siddhiApp = "@App:name('TestExecutionPlan') "
            + "define stream FooStream (test string); "
            + "@info(name = 'query1')  "
            + "@source(type ='rabbitmq', "
            + "uri = 'amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672', "
            + "exchange.name = 'amq.topic', "
            + "exchange.type = 'topic', "
            + "routing.key= '#',"
            + "queue.name = 'siddhi-queue', "
            + "@map(type='text')) "
            + "define stream BarStream (test string); ";
    SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();
    SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(siddhiApp);
    siddhiAppRuntime.addCallback("BarStream", new StreamCallback() {
        @Override
        public void receive(Event[] events) {
            for (Event event : events) {
                EventPrinter.print(event);
                eventCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    });
    siddhiAppRuntime.start();
    SiddhiAppRuntime executionPlanRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(
            "@App:name('TestExecutionPlan') " +
                    "define stream FooStream (test string); " +
                    "@info(name = 'query1') " +
                    "@sink(type ='rabbitmq', uri = 'amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672', " +
                    "exchange.type='topic', " +
                    "exchange.name = 'amq.topic', " +
                    "@map(type='text'))" +
                    "Define stream BarStream (test string);" +
                    "from FooStream select test insert into BarStream;");
    InputHandler fooStream = executionPlanRuntime.getInputHandler("FooStream");
    executionPlanRuntime.start();
    List<Event> arrayList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    arrayList.add(new Event(System.currentTimeMillis(), new Object[]{"WSO2"}));
    arrayList.add(new Event(System.currentTimeMillis(), new Object[]{"IBM"}));
    arrayList.add(new Event(System.currentTimeMillis(), new Object[]{"WSO2"}));
    fooStream.send(arrayList.toArray(new Event[3]));
    SiddhiTestHelper.waitForEvents(waitTime, 3, eventCount, timeout);
    executionPlanRuntime.shutdown();
    siddhiAppRuntime.shutdown();
}
```

Refer the Siddhi Query Quide: [Siddhi-source](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#source)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had not realized.
And my log4j.properties was not configured.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I found the problem.

log4j.properties was not configured.

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
>   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

Comment: Although, the query needs to change